# Excel formula for Racing team (count all driving hours after replacement date)

Tags: excel

I’m having a bit of a difficulty with creating an Excel formula for the attached file (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f8a6a52db305e22c5ddbceb6183830a920180613150327/3a44f3)

For a racing team we would like to keep track of the lifespan of the mounted parts on the vehicle. The file should interactively show the lifespan in hours left (column C), but only for the driven time after the replacement date (column E).

I really have no clue what formula to use and several hours of Google time haven’t helped me anything further…

Anyone who can help me out?

Thanks in advance for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

On Sheet [Parts list], in cell D2, enter:

```
=C2-SUMIF('Driving times'!A:A,">="&MAX(E2,0),'Driving times'!B:B)
```

Copy down.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your quick reply! I had to change the formula a bit, because Excel returned some errors. The final formula looks like this:

```
    =C2-(SUMIF('Driving times'!A:A;">="&MAX(E2;0);'Driving times'!B:B))
```